# How to get the previous working day from Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

We maintain a table listing actual holidays for years to come (`Holidays`, with two columns: `M_DATE`, and `DESCR`). I need to find the most recent day before the given one, that's neither listed in that table, nor is Saturday or Sunday.

Preferably -- without a loop :) How would I do that?

Comment: In some databases (e.g. data warehouses) you'll find a pre-populated "Dates" table with columns such as "DayOfWeek" and "PreviousBusinessDay"

Comment: Can you make any assumptions about how many holidays there will be in a row? If there is never more than say 2 week day holidays in a row you could just look at 5 days before the current day and find the latest one that is neither a weekend day or holiday.

Comment: here is an example similiar to your problem using recursive with  https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3917207/sql-to-exclude-weekends-and-bank-holidays

Comment: The things are a bit more difficult here :) sometimes we have transferred working days to weekend in Russia :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_Saturday

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive query. For example, if you want to find the first holiday before `2021-05-02`:

```sql
WITH start_date (dt) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-05-02' FROM DUAL
),
days ( dt, day, found ) AS (
  SELECT dt,
         TRUNC(dt) - TRUNC(dt, 'IW'),
         0
  FROM   start_date
UNION ALL
  SELECT dt - CASE day WHEN 0 THEN 3 WHEN 6 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN day IN (0, 6, 5) THEN 4 ELSE day - 1 END,
         CASE WHEN m_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM   days d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN holidays h
         ON ( dt - CASE day WHEN 0 THEN 3 WHEN 6 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END = m_date )
  WHERE  found = 0
)
SELECT dt
FROM   days
WHERE  found = 1;
```

And your holidays table is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE holidays ( m_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-04-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-04-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-04-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-04-27' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-04-26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-04-23' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output is:

> | DT |
> | --- |
> | 2021-04-22 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5a1ce7307f2ee67099c49ec4bcd5ce1a)*

Answer (score 0):

If you have a holidays table, the simplest thing is to just include a column in the table which is "the most recent non-holiday, non-weekend".  Presumably, this is why you want this calculation.

To get the earliest holiday in a sequence of holidays, you can use a gaps-and-islands approach:

```
select h.*,
       (case when to_char(first_holiday_mdate, 'DY') = 'MON'   -- Monday
             then first_holiday_mdate - interval '3' day
             when to_char(first_holiday_mdate, 'DY') = 'SUN'   -- Sunday
             then first_holiday_mdate - interval '2' day
             else first_holiday_mdate - interval '1' day
        end) as last_working_day_before_holiday
from (select h.*,
             min(mdate) over (partition by mdate - seqnum) as first_holiday_mdate
      from (select h.*,
                   row_number() over (order by mdate) as seqnum
            from holidays h
           ) h
     ) h;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8cf0d082847c4a8f975b6019b44fe73) is a little db<>fiddle.

Note:  This assumes English is language for the day of the week.  This is just for convenience; internationalization settings are not really relevant to solving the problem and can easily be incorporated.

EDIT:

Based on MTOs comments, here is an alternative way of expressing the grouping logic that takes weekends into account:

```
select h.*,
       (case when to_char(first_holiday_mdate, 'DY') = 'MON'   -- Monday
             then first_holiday_mdate - interval '3' day
             when to_char(first_holiday_mdate, 'DY') = 'SUN'   -- Sunday
             then first_holiday_mdate - interval '2' day
             else first_holiday_mdate - interval '1' day
        end) as last_working_day_before_holiday
from (select h.*, min(mdate) over (partition by holiday_grp order by mdate) as first_holiday_mdate
      from (select h.*,
                   sum(case when to_char(mdate, 'DY') = 'MON' and prev_mdate >= mdate - interval '3' day
                            then 0
                            when to_char(mdate, 'DY') = 'SUN' and prev_mdate >= mdate - interval '2' day
                            then 0
                            when to_char(mdate, 'DY') <> 'MON' and prev_mdate = mdate - interval '1' day
                            then 0
                            else 1
                       end) over (order by mdate) as holiday_grp
                            
            from (select h.*,
                         lag(mdate) over (order by mdate) as prev_mdate
                  from holidays h
                 ) h
           ) h
     ) h
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3dacc7f68b6f5b40e75e3d5790684d92) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It runs now but it doesn't seem to take into account that holidays may appear on Friday and the following Monday [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f7596aeccabc5f3b394f58c71021d44).

Comment: @MT0 . . . The results look correct in the fiddle you set up.  The last working day is 2021-04-23 for all but the earliest date -- and that is correct, at least that is how I interpret the question.  The `case` expression takes the day of the week into account.

Comment: `2021-04-23` is in the list of holiday dates; it should not appear as one of the "last working day before holiday".

Comment: @MT0 . . . I think the current solution works, but your fiddle is missing 2021-04-21 and the day of the week descriptions are not correct.

Comment: Yes, my mistake with the data that I hadn't spotted.

Comment: @MT0 . . . I am impressed with your debugging skills in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have the following dates in your table and `m_date` is indexed:

```sql
create table holidays(m_date,descr) as (
  select date'2021-04-30', '2021-04-30' from dual union all
  select date'2021-04-29', '2021-04-29' from dual union all
  select date'2021-04-28', '2021-04-28' from dual
);

create index holidays_ix on holidays(m_date);
```

1st variant:

```sql
select *
from (select trunc(sysdate)-level as dt from dual connect by level<=36600) dates_generator
where not exists(select/*+ no_unnest */ 1 from holidays h where h.m_date=dates_generator.dt)
and rownum=1;
```

It works ~0.00025 sec with the following plan:

```
Plan hash value: 2685405438

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name        | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |             |        |       |     3 (100)|          |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                  |             |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
|*  2 |   FILTER                        |             |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
|   3 |    VIEW                         |             |      1 |     6 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   4 |     CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|             |        |       |            |          |  2048 |  2048 | 2048  (0)|
|   5 |      FAST DUAL                  |             |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|*  6 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | HOLIDAYS_IX |      1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
   2 - filter( IS NULL)
   6 - access("H"."M_DATE"=:B1)


SQL_ID           PLAN_HV  ELAEXE   CPU_TIME
------------- ---------- ------- ----------
4hfsgdbqh4h4v 2685405438  .00018 .000144533
```

2nd variant:

```sql
with dates_generator(dt, flag) as (
   select 
      trunc(sysdate)-1 as dt, 
      case when trunc(sysdate)-1 in (select h.m_date from holidays h)
             then 1
             else 0
      end flag
   from dual
   union all
   select 
      dt-1,
      case when exists (select h.m_date from holidays h where h.m_date=dt-1)
             then 1
             else 0
      end flag
   from dates_generator
   where flag=1
   and dt>= (select min(h.m_date)-1 from holidays h)
)
select dt
from dates_generator
where flag=0 and rownum=1;
```

It works a bit longer 0.00029 seconds with the following plan:

```sql
Plan hash value: 2143177677

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                  | Name        | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                           |             |        |       |    34 (100)|          |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                             |             |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
|*  2 |   VIEW                                     |             |      2 |    24 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   3 |    UNION ALL (RECURSIVE WITH) BREADTH FIRST|             |        |       |            |          |  2048 |  2048 | 2048  (0)|
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                       | HOLIDAYS_IX |      1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   5 |     FAST DUAL                              |             |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                       | HOLIDAYS_IX |      1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   7 |     RECURSIVE WITH PUMP                    |             |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
|   8 |      SORT AGGREGATE                        |             |      1 |     8 |            |          |       |       |          |
|   9 |       INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)            | HOLIDAYS_IX |      3 |    24 |            |          |       |       |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
   2 - filter("FLAG"=0)
   4 - access("H"."M_DATE"=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)-1)
   6 - access("H"."M_DATE"=:B1-1)

SQL_ID           PLAN_HV  ELAEXE   CPU_TIME
------------- ---------- ------- ----------
4gr1nqxhv7n4y 2143177677  .00052   .0004531
```

Second one is about 3 times slower.

There is also a much more readable variant:

```sql
select trunc(sysdate)-gen.n as dt
from xmltable('1 to 36000' columns n for ordinality) gen
where not exists (select 1 from holidays h where h.m_date=trunc(sysdate)-gen.n)
and rownum=1;
```

But it's much slower then previous variants, because of `xmltable()`: 1.4ms

```sql
Plan hash value: 2155686814

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name                  | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                       |        |       |     3 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                        |                       |        |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   FILTER                              |                       |        |       |            |          |
|   3 |    VIEW                               |                       |     21 |   273 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     COUNT                             |                       |        |       |            |          |
|   5 |      COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| XQSEQUENCEFROMXMLTYPE |     21 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | HOLIDAYS_IX           |      1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
   2 - filter( IS NULL)
   6 - access("H"."M_DATE"=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)-:B1)

SQL_ID           PLAN_HV  ELAEXE   CPU_TIME
------------- ---------- ------- ----------
2km7q5zx20y00 2155686814  .00141 .001382846
```

**Update: I've updated queries (found a few bugs)**

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=70b8facdd5454640c8c5619091b3771a)

Comment: I can't get any of these queries to give the correct answer of `2021-04-22` for this data [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1e61aedf7586372e7ebcb6ad3829d804) and they all give different (wrong) answers.

Comment: oh, thanks, fixed 1st and second queries. 3rd one was correct

Comment: They still are not correct as `2021-04-25` is a Sunday. As I mentioned in the previous comment, the correct answer should be `2021-04-22` for the db<>fiddle I provided.

Answer (score 0):

With a hint from the (more complicated) [question 43747355](/questions/43747355/), I got the following to work:

```sql
select max(day) from (select (TO_DATE(:Today, 'YYYYMMDD')) - level as day
        from dual connect by level <= 10
) days
where days.day not in (select M_DATE from Holidays)
and TO_CHAR(days.day, 'D') not in (1, 7)
```

The `level` used with `dual` seems rather despicable, but it does give the sequence of days, that can be selected from, etcætera...

Comment: This is simple and concise; however, the downsides are that: you need to know the maximum number of days you are going to search backwards (and if the company wants to have a 2 week shutdown over Christmas and your range is only 10 days then it would return `NULL`); and that `TO_CHAR( ..., 'D' )` has different behaviour when the database is in different international settings (as different countries start the week on different days). You can fix the latter issue using `TRUNC(days.day) - TRUNC(days.day, 'IW') NOT IN (5, 6)` which works on ISO weeks and has the same behaviour in all territories.

Comment: Thanks. Neither is a concern in our case -- I need only the US _banking_ holidays, and the locale is always American too. But noted...