# How to get last workday before holiday in Oracle

Tags: oracle

need help for some oracle stuff ..

I need to get Day-1 from sysdate, holiday and weekend will be excluded .

And for holiday, we need to get the range to get the last workday before holiday.

The start date and end date will coming from my holiday table.

ex :
Holiday Table

| HolidayName | Start_date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| holiday1 | 5th Aug'21 | 6th Aug'21 |

condition :
this query run on 9th Aug 2021

expected result :
4th Aug'21

I've tried some query and function but I just can't get what I need.

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
select max(d) as last_workday
from (select trunc(sysdate)-level as d from dual connect by level < 30) prior_month
where to_char(d, 'DY') not in ('SAT','SUN')
  and not exists (select holidayname from holiday_table 
                  where prior_month.d between start_date and end_date) 
;
```

Without seeing your Holiday table, it's hard to say how many days back you would need to look to find the last workday. If you have a holiday that lasts for more than 30 days, you'll need to change the `30` to a larger number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple case expression to determine what day of the week the start of your holiday is, then subtract a number of days based on that.

```sql
WITH
    holiday (holidayname, start_date, end_date)
    AS
        (SELECT 'holiday1', DATE '2021-8-5', DATE '2021-8-6' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Christmas', DATE '2021-12-25', DATE '2021-12-26' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'July 4th', DATE '2021-7-4', DATE '2021-7-5' FROM DUAL)
SELECT holidayname,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       start_date - CASE TO_CHAR (start_date, 'Dy') WHEN 'Mon' THEN 3 WHEN 'Sun' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END    AS prior_business_day
  FROM holiday;
```

```
   HOLIDAYNAME    START_DATE     END_DATE    PRIOR_BUSINESS_DAY
______________ _____________ ____________ _____________________
holiday1       05-AUG-21     06-AUG-21    04-AUG-21
Christmas      25-DEC-21     26-DEC-21    24-DEC-21
July 4th       04-JUL-21     05-JUL-21    02-JUL-21
```

Comment: this one also working and given the right result, thanks a lot for your help !! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67326643/1509264):

```sql
WITH start_date (dt) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-05-02' FROM DUAL
),
days ( dt, day, found ) AS (
  SELECT dt,
         TRUNC(dt) - TRUNC(dt, 'IW'),
         0
  FROM   start_date
UNION ALL
  SELECT dt - CASE day WHEN 0 THEN 3 WHEN 6 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN day IN (0, 6, 5) THEN 4 ELSE day - 1 END,
         CASE WHEN h.start_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM   days d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN holidays h
         ON ( dt - CASE day WHEN 0 THEN 3 WHEN 6 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
              BETWEEN h.start_date AND h.end_date )
  WHERE  found = 0
)
SELECT dt
FROM   days
WHERE  found = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE holidays (HolidayName, Start_date, End_Date) AS
SELECT 'holiday1', DATE '2021-08-05', DATE '2021-08-06' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DT |
> | --- |
> | 2021-08-04 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8b5508e09b48b89a9009a9718e2d6d11)*

Comment: thanks a lot for help but this one still not give the proper result .. but really appreciate :)

Comment: @ImeldaSusanto What data is giving the wrong answer? I have not found any errors with my testing and it gives the expected output for your inputs, so if you can put together a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8b5508e09b48b89a9009a9718e2d6d11) with the data that fails then I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's very efficient. Did it just for fun

```
create table holidays (
  holiday_name varchar2(100) primary key,
  start_date date not null,
  end_date date not null
)
/

Table created

insert into holidays (holiday_name, start_date, end_date)
values ('holiday1', date '2021-08-05', date '2021-08-06');

1 row inserted

with days_before(day, wrk_day) as
 (select trunc(sysdate - 1) d,
         case
           when h.holiday_name is not null then 0
           when to_char(trunc(sysdate - 1), 'D') in ('6', '7') then 0
           else 1
         end work_day
    from dual
    left join holidays h
      on trunc(sysdate - 1) between h.start_date and h.end_date
  union all
  select db.day - 1,
         case
           when h.holiday_name is not null then 0
           when to_char(db.day - 1, 'D') in ('6', '7') then 0
           else 1
         end work_day
    from days_before db
    left join holidays h
      on db.day - 1 between h.start_date and h.end_date
   where db.wrk_day = 0) search depth first by day set order_no
select day from days_before where wrk_day = 1;

DAY
-----------
04.08.2021
```

Comment: thanks a lot for help ! 
this query still not given the correct date but really appreciate your answer :)